# Altering styles in ctools automodal generated automodal

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

So as my post history shows that I happen to like the [Ctools Automodal](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal) module to carry me out of difficult Ctools logic to render a modal. It works as intended on a callback from `hook_menu()`, but I have no control over the style of the Modal generated, colors, size, and et cetera (typically set using a JS object in a pre_render hook with a `drupal_add_js()` call.) What's the best approach to do this, if its at all possible using this module?